# How to get procedure cache hit ratio in sybase by using query?

Tags: sybase

I have installed sybase setup in my local now I want check the procedure cache Hit ratio by using query.

Please help on this, because I am new on sybase and I need to collect procedure cache hit ratio for some purpose.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage)?  If ASE, try running `sp_sysmon` to see if the procedure cache portion of the output gives you what you want, otherwise please provide more details on what you're looking for re: procedure cache hit ratio (eg, just a number/%? break down by the different areas within proc cache? breakdown by object type, and perhaps db? something else?)

Comment: Hi I dont have much idea on it, but on google I got this (Adaptive Server should be able to find an unused tree or plan in the procedure cache for the most common procedures. The percentage of times the server finds an available plan in cache is called the cache hit ratio) , so more checking I got one query(sp_monitorconfig “procedure cache size”) by this I am getting size but I want (procedure cache hit ratio)

Comment: As MarkP already put you would usually get the cache hit ratio per cache from sp_sysmon usually for ASE. The sp_monitorconfig is more useful for procedure cache reuse and other counters. You can restrict options to just get cache info if needed via sp_sysmon - see http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00842.1502/html/spsysmon/spsysmon8.htm