# How to get cache hit ratio?

Tags: sql, caching, sybase

If I already know physical reads and logical reads from disk, then how to collect hit ratio. it is there any formula to collect it?

Comment: `(LR - PR) / LR`, but hard to tell with this little information

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181588/how-to-get-procedure-cache-hit-ratio-in-sybase-by-using-query

Comment: that is particular for Procedure cache hit ratio by query, and this one is for calculate cache hit ratio by using formula so I can calculate both **procedure** and **Data cache hit ratio**

Comment: Same answer applies - sp_sysmon is used data cache hit ratio as well. The data is shown per cache under the caches results portion of sysmon.